# How can I get a libp2p rendezvous server running?

Tags: ipfs, libp2p

I'm trying to get a [libp2p rendezvous server](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p-websocket-star-rendezvous) working. Has anybody been able to do this here? I would love some help.
I installed the docker version, as they suggest:

```
docker pull libp2p/websocket-star-rendezvous:release
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --name rendezvous libp2p/websocket-star-rendezvous:release
```

The logs say it's running at 0.0.0.0:9090, but when I try to connect to it via IPFS or via a simple javascript call, neither work. It returns an ERR_CONN_REFUSED.

```
this._ipfs = new Ipfs({                                                      
  EXPERIMENTAL: {                                                            
    pubsub: true                                                             
  },                                                         
  config: {                                                            
    Bootstrap: [                                                             
      "/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star/",   
    ]
  }
});
```

Note: I have my own URL but I'l just using the URLs from the examples now.

```
websocket = new WebSocket("wss://ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io:443");
```

In the client, I get a simple validation error: [2](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p-websocket-star/issues/59#issuecomment-431613180) "0" must be in IPFS format

On the server, I get nothing in the logs and refused connections. This is all mostly just "out-of-the-box" with no code changes at all.

More detailed in the GH issue [here](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p-websocket-star/issues/59#issuecomment-431613180). Help!

Answer (score 0):

This repo should work very well: [simple-bootstrap-node](https://github.com/BenDerPan/simple-bootstrap-node)